# Node Slack SDK. RTM disconnecting event

Tags: slack, slack-api

Tell me which analogue for the:

```
rtm.on('disconnected', () => {...})
```

, which was in version 3, is in version 4?

And where you can find a list of events that can be intercepted by `rtm.on(...)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 4.x the `'disconnected'` event is similar to the `'disconnect'` event from version 3.x.

The full list of events (and the translation from v3 to v4) is available [in the migration guide](https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk/wiki/Migration-Guide-for-v4#events).

I highly recommend using the latest version. The project will soon be transitioning to version 5.x, so using 3.x will keep you further away from all the improvements. I also recommend reading the whole RTM Client section of that migration guide.